# Why doesn't the server receive my second command from the client?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

The server is already set up. I connected to it and got it to return any data. The received data printed for the first piece of data that I sent. But then I tried to send something else, which, in theory, should return another string, but it just says that it's still expecting it.

At the moment, this is my code:

```
import socket
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('ServerHostHere', PortNumberHere))
clientsocket.send('hello')
dataOne = clientsocket.recv(2048)
print(dataOne)
```

This returned : "Hello to you too!"

Then I tried sending another piece of information:

```
clientsocket.send('How are you?')
dataTwo = clientsocket.recv(1024)
print(dataTwo)
```

Instead of returning a line, it just says "Error, expecting command question") meaning that it didn't receive my second command.

Is my code wrong or am I supposed to add something else?

Comment: What about the server code?

Comment: @CristiFati I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: The error seems to come from the server, how about posting the server code as well?